# How to dynamically set circular imageviews with custom background colours

Tags: android

I have been doing some research and even tried to implement various solutions, but I have not been able to come across any solution that has worked. What I am trying to do is display a bunch of `CardViews` that each have an `ImageView` attached to them in order to represent different products for an inventory management system, however, there won't be actual images, rather different coloured circles that will be decided upon the user. I provided a base example below of what my cards look like.

[image]

Essentially, a long list of products will be presented, but with all the `ImageViews` in a circular format, as well as the colour that was selected by the user, which is in the form of a Hex value, so that they land up with this colourful list of products. Like I said before, I have tried various solutions such as implementing classes through Gradle to aid with this, however, it will not work for the `android:background` property and only the `android:src` property, so even though an image will be in the form of a circle, the background remains a square.

Another basic example you can look at is Google's accounts. When someone creates a new account and they don't provide a profile picture, they are given a default coloured circle with their initials. I essentially want the same thing. Any advice or assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One a possible easy solution will be to use `ShapeableImageView`

```
    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ImageCircleTheme"
        app:strokeColor="#FF0000"
        app:strokeWidth="4dp" />
```

with style

```
    <style name="ImageCircleTheme">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    </style>
```

and dynamically change the color of your stroke via `strokeColor(...)` or `setStrokeColorResource(...)`

if you need only round circle inside ImageView just generate the round bitmap with color that you need

```
private fun generateRoundBitmap(): RoundedBitmapDrawable {
        val color = "0xfff44336".toInt()
        val drawable = ColorDrawable(color)
        val icon = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(requireContext().resources, drawable.toBitmap(100, 100))
        icon.isCircular = true
        return icon
    }
```

and set it into your `ImageView`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Won't this solution only give me an outline though?

Comment: It's inherited from ImageView, you can load round images into it

Comment: Alright. I understand that. However, it doesn't really solve my problem, cause I need the inside of the `ShapeableImageView` to also be coloured in. What you provided above only gives me an outline, and trying to add a colour to it only makes it square again.

Comment: So you need only colored circle inside your `ImageView`?

Comment: Yes. I figured out a way to do it and will post an answer now. It only just hit me today

Answer (score 0):

I managed figure out a little bit of a workaround for those wanting to create `ImageViews` where the background colour can dynamically change. All you will need to have is an `PNG` of a sqaure with a transparent circle in the middle, where the colour of your square will need to match the colour of the background that your `ImageView` is on. For example, my `Card` has a white background and therefore my square will be just white. With this you can set the `android:background` property to any colour you like, and then all you need to do is set the `android:src:` property to reference the square `PNG`

It's a little bit of a janky method of doing so, but it is a quick fix. I will show the `PNG` I am talking about below, as well as the result and an example.

**PNG**
A square with a transparent Circle.
[image]

**The Result**

[image]

**Example XML code**

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_image"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|start"
            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
            android:background="#2894BF"
            android:src="@drawable/circle"/>
```